# Ubuntu Install Issues - boots to purple screen

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 dual booted with Windows 10 on my PC and whenever I press try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu it gets stuck on the purple Ubuntu splash screen. Please help if you can, any help will be awesome! Thanks,

I am using a USB - I can not use CD as my laptop does not have one.  I have also tried re-install USB image, but still to no avail.  on the screen I get a logo and like 6 dots,one time I got 3 white dots another time I got 4 white dots but then just stops.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips(may not be the exact answer) based on my past experience:

1. Disable secure boot completely in BIOS
2. Switch off hibernation feature of Windows 10
3. Please make sure that the .iso you have downloaded in not corrupted
   may be you can try it in another computer.
4. In case you have a graphics card, provide the information and also
   information about the overall system configuration